# Duplicate Entry on update of non primary key column

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table called indice_hora with 6 columns:

```
- date (pk)         | Composite
- agent_id (pk)     | Primary Key
- contagem          
- movimento         
- preenchimento    
- state_changes
```

I recently added the state_changes column without a default value, so now I'm trying to update all null values to 0.

I'm trying to run this code:

```
update indice_hora
set state_changes = 0
where state_changes is null;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
[2019-01-25 08:55:38] [23000][1062] Duplicate entry '2019-01-25 08:55:38-0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Why am I getting this error even if I do not update any key values?

OBS 1: This table does not have any row with date '2019-01-25 08:55:38-0'.
OBS 2: This table is mainly updated by a trigger:

```
create trigger update_indice_hora_table
  after INSERT
  on indice
  for each row
  INSERT INTO indice_hora VALUES (DATE_FORMAT(NEW.data_hora_registro, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'), NEW.id_agent, NEW.contagem, NEW.mobilidade, NEW.preenchimento, 0)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE indice_hora.data            = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.data_hora_registro, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'),
                          indice_hora.id_agent        = NEW.id_agent,
                          indice_hora.contagem        = ((indice_hora.contagem      + NEW.contagem)       / 2),
                          indice_hora.movimento       = ((indice_hora.movimento     + NEW.mobilidade)     / 2),
                          indice_hora.preenchimento   = ((indice_hora.preenchimento + NEW.preenchimento)  / 2);
```

EDIT 1: Looks like '2019-01-25 08:55:38-0' was the current time when I rode the program. Every time I run the script the duplicated entry is the current time.

Comment: You are performing INSERT again rather than update on each row after INSERT as per the trigger. You could see it.

Comment: If i edit "set state_changes = 0" to "set state_changes = 0, date = indice_hora.date" the error is gone. Why?

Comment: The insert trigger is on the "indice" table, but I'm updating the "indice_hora" table. This should not be influenced by the trigger, right?

Comment: yeah. That's true. But, if there is any sort of bindings between indice and indice_hora, like if indice_hora updates, also update indice, then this will cause the same issue. And one more thing, try to perform update keeping all the primary keys in constrainsts.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the trigger -> Run your update Command ->Enable the trigger back.

**1 Disable Trigger**

```
ALTER TRIGGER <TRIGGER_NAME> DISABLE
```

**2 Execute Your Query**

**3 EnableTrigger**

```
ALTER TRIGGER <TRIGGER_NAME> ENABLE
```